# Prayer for the Government if the President or VP is female

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, nuschaot, politics-government, grammatical-gender

The prayer Hanosen Teshuah as recited in the US has the line את הנשיא ואת משנהו. To me, these terms sound masculine. If the President and/or Vice President of the United States were female, would this line need to be modified, or are these terms considered gender neutral? If they should be modified, then how exactly?

(If I were to guess, it seems like a woman who is president should be called a nesiah, and the VP might be referred to as mishneha, mishnaso, or mishnasah as the case might be.

The rest of the pronouns in some siddurim are plural, so that seems OK for any case. If they are singular I assume they would be switched to feminine like the version used in the UK for the Queen, but it would be good to know for sure.)

Comment: Anyone have a modern German Siddur to check?

Comment: Are there separate words for Chancellor and President?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know how it affects the tefillah, but Angela Merkel uses the masculine "Bundeskanzler," rather than the feminine "Bundeskanzlerin." I'm not sure why.

Comment: Cislunar, Chancellor is an office equivalent to that of a prime minister, so at least in Israel (where they presumably don't say Hanotein Teshuah) you've got a nasi (Pres.) and a rosh hamemshalah (PM)

Comment: I believe that somewhere there is a version of this modified for both the Queen and King of England.